# Python: Why return statment isn't working?

Tags: python

I have a really strange problem, the return isnt working. 
My code:

```
def data_for_dump(action = None , type_of_dump = None, where_is_price = None, check = 'false', currentQty=None, unrealisedRoePcnt=None, last_price=None):
    if type_of_dump == 'control_panels':
        data = {
            'Action':{
                'Action':action,
                'Where_is_price':where_is_price,
            }
        }

        #return data
    elif type_of_dump == 'get_position_info':
        data = {
            'Info':{
                'check':check,
                'currentQty':currentQty,
                'unrealisedRoePcnt':unrealisedRoePcnt,
                'last_price':last_price,
            }
        }
    return data
```

When I'm call this function like this

```
data_for__dump = data_for_dump(action = 'set_location',type_of_dump = 'control_panels', where_is_price = price_location)
```

Its returns me:

```
<function data_for_dump at 0x7f409cdd7510>
```

What a hell is it?

Comment: Fix your indentation first.

Comment: The issue might be as simple as the indentation. After the first line indent all the other lines.

Comment: the variables you are using look very similar. are you sure that you are evaluating "data_for__dump" with 2 underscores to check the return value of the function "data_for_dump"?

Comment: Runs fine on my computer, did you print `data_for__dump ` or `data_for_dump`?

Comment: Seems to be running fine on the online interpreter as well: https://repl.it/languages/python3. I am sure you are printing data_for_dump. Can you check?

Comment: Side note: see [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for python style guidelines. Also consider changing you function definition, 7 arguments, all with default values make a very long and not very readable function. Maybe object of some kind or a dictionary should be used as a parameter instead of 7 bare arguments?

Answer (score 1):

The following below works fine on my computer.

Your function name is `data_for_dump`, but that is what you are calling the variable that the function is returning. Then, when you are trying to actually call that function to return a value, you are calling `data_for__dump`, that extra `_` character matters.

It was returning the function as a string. Simply correcting the `_` to call the function and switching your variable name fixes your issue.

```
def data_for_dump(action = None , type_of_dump = None, where_is_price = None, check = 'false', currentQty=None, unrealisedRoePcnt=None, last_price=None):
    if type_of_dump == 'control_panels':
        data = {
            'Action':{
                'Action':action,
                'Where_is_price':where_is_price
                }
            }

        #return data
    elif type_of_dump == 'get_position_info':
        data = {
            'Info':{
                'check':check,
                'currentQty':currentQty,
                'unrealisedRoePcnt':unrealisedRoePcnt,
                'last_price':last_price
            }
        }

    return data

def main():
    data = data_for_dump(action = 'set_location',type_of_dump = 'control_panels', where_is_price = 3)
    print(data)
# Yields {'Action': {'Action': 'set_location', 'Where_is_price': 3}}

main()
```

Comment: "It was returning the location in memory where that function is stored. " No it is not, it is returning the *function object itself*.

Comment: The hex return statement is the location in the register where that object is stored, no?

Comment: In the register? It is the standard `__repr__` output for function objects, but that is because a *function object is being printed*. It is no more the location in memory than `class Foo: pass; f = Foo(); print(f)`. `f` is a `Foo` object, not a location in memory. The default string representation only happens to print that

Comment: Ah okay. Apologies. I figured that hex value was the object's memory location, like in C, which Python is based on. Editing question now...

Comment: That value in the printed output *does* represent the memory address of the function object on the heap, but that isn't what is *being printed*. It is *printing the function itself*. When you print that function, you get that output, because that is how the `__repr__` hook is implemented. And again, it isn't *the function as a string*, it *is the function itself*. same as `def func() pass; print(func); print(type(func))`. Functions are first-class objects in Python. It seems the OP simply printed the function object, because of similar names, as you point out.

Answer (score 0):

If are displaying data_for_dump, it is expected. I think you would want to print data_for__dump instead.